# Tag cleanup needed for [lang]

Tags: discussion, clean-up

[lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lang) has a lot of ill-fitting questions, and when I saw it at first I assumed it was a great candidate for burninating. But then I realized that the HTML `lang` attribute fits very nicely and there's a good core of questions already using it for that reason. So instead of burninating, let's clean up the assorted (~177) questions using that to make sure they're consistent.

I've already submitted a tag wiki edit to make it plain what it should mean, so for now no synonymization/renaming should be necessary, but this may need to be revisited later if it keeps getting messy.

Comment: How embarrassing, I forgot and hit Ask Question on this before finishing the writeup on the wiki.

Comment: I'm thinking of proposing to rename as [html-lang] instead if that's the case for clarity. But there is also [CSS' `:lang`](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang)? PHP's Laravel also has [`Lang`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/localization) class. There are many more, but I stopped analyzing for now.

Comment: @AndrewT. In that case, Laravel's should be renamed at least. Putting largely unrelated things together is not particularly helpful, and an element's attribute has little in common with a PHP class.

Comment: @AndrewT. tags for html markup elements have been [merged](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/synonyms)/deleted in the past for utterly pointless.

Comment: I feel like [tag:lang] in the content of HTML probably *could* be replaced by the pair ([tag:html] [tag:localization])... but that doesn't mean it *should* be, especially since [tag:localization] seems so rarely used.  Unless you're talking about `<script lang=` (which really isn't a thing, but probably draws questions)

Comment: @BenVoigt we shouldn't optimize tags for misconceived questions like your last example, I think.